# Fortran subroutine value keyword

Tags: fortran, subroutine

I have a FORTRAN file "testValueKeyword.for" contains following code

```
  subroutine intersub2(x,y)
    integer, value ::  x
    integer y
    x = x + y
    y = x*y
  print *, 'in subroutine after changing: ', x, y
  end subroutine

  program testValueKeyword
    integer :: x = 10, y = 20
    print *, 'before calling: ', x, y
    call intersub(x, y)
    print *, 'after calling: ', x, y
    x = 10
    y = 20
    call intersub2(x, y)
  contains
  subroutine intersub(x,y)
    integer, value ::  x
    integer y
    x = x + y
    y = x*y
    print *, 'in subroutine after changing: ', x, y
  end subroutine
  end program
```

the subroutine intersub and intersub2 contain the same code, both passing the x argument by value, but the intersub2 seems passing a large random integer similar to memory address. I get different y values after running. could you explain this to me?

Comment: The random integer similar to memory address is actually the address inside the initialised data segment where `x` from the main program is being stored.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place subroutine intersub2 into a module and `use` that module from the caller, here program testValueKeyword, so that the caller "knows" the calling convention to use.   When you use "advanced" argument features of Fortran >=90 in a procedure (subroutine or function), you need to make the interface explicit to the caller so that the caller uses the same interface / calling conventions as the procedure.  Otherwise an inconsistency between caller and callee will cause "random" communication between the two.   The easiest way to make the interface known is to place the procedure into a module and `use` that module.  You could also describe the procedure with an `interface`, but that's more work and a second thing to maintain.

When I compile your code with gfortran with extensive warning options, gfortran even tells me of the problem:

```
call intersub2(x, y)
                  1
Error: Dummy argument 'x' of procedure 'intersub2' at (1) has an attribute that requires an explicit interface for this procedure
```

If you are using gfortran, try these compiler options for debugging: `-O2  -fimplicit-none  -Wall  -Wline-truncation  -Wcharacter-truncation  -Wsurprising  -Waliasing  -Wimplicit-interface  -Wunused-parameter  -fwhole-file  -fcheck=all  -std=f2008  -pedantic  -fbacktrace`

Answer (score 0):

As MSB says, the program `testValueKeyword` does not know what `intersub2` is, so it is no surprise that you get junk data.

As an alternative to MSB's suggestion of writing a `MODULE`, you could also put `intersub2` in the `CONTAINS` portion of the program and get the correct results.